# Sorting imports fails on Python VSCode extension

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-extensions

### Background

I have an anaconda environment that has Python 3.7 installed. I have a file with some imports out of order which I want VScode to order when pressing `CRTL+s`.

However, instead or ordering the imports, there is a crash and nothing happens.

### Problem

When I press `CRTL+s` on my VScode, I get a pop up saying the Python extension crashes. After some investigation, this is the stack-trace I found:

```
Error 2021-10-15 16:00:05: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.10.1336267007/pythonFiles/sortImports.py", line 12, in <module>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.10.1336267007/pythonFiles/sortImports.py", line 12, in <module>

Error 2021-10-15 16:00:05: Failed to format imports for '/home/user/Workplace/work/my-project/cars/client.py'. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.10.1336267007/pythonFiles/sortImports.py", line 12, in <module>

Error 2021-10-15 16:00:05:     import isort.main
  File "/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.10.1336267007/pythonFiles/lib/python/isort/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from . import settings
  File "/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.10.1336267007/pythonFiles/lib/python/isort/settings.py", line 5, in <module>
    import configparser
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my-project/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 147, in <module>
    import re
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my-project/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 124, in <module>
    import enum
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my-project/lib/python3.7/enum.py", line 2, in <module>
    from types import MappingProxyType, DynamicClassAttribute
  File "/home/user/Workplace/work/my-project/cars/types.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pathlib import Path
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my-project/lib/python3.7/pathlib.py", line 13, in <module>
    from urllib.parse import quote_from_bytes as urlquote_from_bytes
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my-project/lib/python3.7/urllib/parse.py", line 627, in <module>
    _asciire = re.compile('([\x00-\x7f]+)')
AttributeError: module 're' has no attribute 'compile'
```

I don't see any issues with my setup. For more information, this is my `conda` env setup:

```
name: my-project
channels:
  - pytorch
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
  - _openmp_mutex=4.5=1_gnu
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - ca-certificates=2021.9.30=h06a4308_1
  - certifi=2021.10.8=py37h06a4308_0
  - cpuonly=1.0=0
  - intel-openmp=2021.3.0=h06a4308_3350
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.35.1=h7274673_9
  - libffi=3.3=he6710b0_2
  - libgcc-ng=9.3.0=h5101ec6_17
  - libgomp=9.3.0=h5101ec6_17
  - libstdcxx-ng=9.3.0=hd4cf53a_17
  - libuv=1.40.0=h7b6447c_0
  - mkl=2021.3.0=h06a4308_520
  - ncurses=6.2=he6710b0_1
  - ninja=1.10.2=hff7bd54_1
  - openssl=1.1.1l=h7f8727e_0
  - pip=21.2.2=py37h06a4308_0
  - pytest-mock=3.6.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - python=3.7.11=h12debd9_0
  - pytorch=1.9.1=py3.7_cpu_0
  - readline=8.1=h27cfd23_0
  - setuptools=58.0.4=py37h06a4308_0
  - sqlite=3.36.0=hc218d9a_0
  - tk=8.6.11=h1ccaba5_0
  - torchaudio=0.9.1=py37
  - typing-extensions=3.10.0.2=hd3eb1b0_0
  - typing_extensions=3.10.0.2=pyh06a4308_0
  - wheel=0.37.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - xz=5.2.5=h7b6447c_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=h7b6447c_3
  - pip:
    - argcomplete==1.12.3
    - attrs==21.2.0
    - babel==2.9.1
    - beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
    - black==21.9b0
    - charset-normalizer==2.0.4
    - click==7.1.2
    - colorama==0.4.4
    - colorclass==2.2.0
    - commonmark==0.9.1
    - dataclasses==0.6
    - docutils==0.16
    - humanize==3.11.0
    - idna==3.2
    - imagesize==1.2.0
    - importlib-metadata==4.8.1
    - iniconfig==1.1.1
    - jinja2==3.0.1
    - m2r==0.2.1
    - markupsafe==2.0.1
    - mistune==0.8.4
    - mypy==0.910
    - mypy-extensions==0.4.3
    - nodeenv==1.6.0
    - numpy==1.21.2
    - packaging==21.0
    - pathspec==0.9.0
    - pillow==8.3.2
    - platformdirs==2.4.0
    - pluggy==1.0.0
    - py==1.10.0
    - pygments==2.10.0
    - pyparsing==2.4.7
    - pyright==0.0.10
    - pytest==6.2.5
    - pytest-describe==2.0.0
    - pytz==2021.1
    - pyyaml==5.4.1
    - regex==2021.10.8
    - requests==2.26.0
    - requests-toolbelt==0.9.1
    - responses==0.13.4
    - rich==10.12.0
    - six==1.16.0
    - snowballstemmer==2.1.0
    - soupsieve==2.2.1
    - tests==0.7
    - toml==0.10.2
    - tomli==1.2.1
    - torch==1.9.1+cpu
    - typed-ast==1.4.3
    - types-pyyaml==5.4.12
    - types-requests==2.25.11
    - upolygon==0.1.6
    - urllib3==1.26.6
    - zipp==3.5.0
variables:
  PYTHONPATH: .
prefix: /home/user/anaconda3/envs/my-project
```

At first I thought it could be a dependency issue, so I started removing every extra dependency I could find.

However, even after doing it, My vscode extension is still not working.

### Questions

- What is wrong with my setup?
- How can I fix it?

Comment: once you are on vscode,open a terminal (Terminal-->New terminal), do you see if your virtual env (myenv) is activated after `CTRL+S` ?

Comment: Yes, it is activated.

Comment: from the terminal, review the packages `pip freeze`, python version. Then run the program `python program.py`. This will ensure the env is in good shape. if you still get the error `module 're' has no attribute 'compile'` then `urllib` seems to have an issue.

Comment: Do you have any file names `re` in your workspace? And can you find the `compile` function in the "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my-project/lib/python3.7/re.py"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reason

The problem here is that I had broken dependencies which would not allow me to do any updates nor new installs.

This had to do with having packages from both `conda` and `pip`. Some of them play nice together, some don't.

### Solution

My solution, was unfortunately, rather atomic. I deleted the environment and created a new one with Python 3.7.
Upon doing that, I also added an extra conda channel `conda-forge` which I recommend instead of `pip`.

Once I did that I installed all the dependencies and packages using `conda` and it worked.

### Commands

Here are the command I used:

```
conda create -n my-project python=3.7
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
conda env config vars set PYTHONPATH="."
conda deactivate
conda activate my-project
```

And then `conda isntall ...` the packages you need.