# How to make VSCode read`isort` config from a file?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, isort

I want to store `isort` config in a repository (as I do with `.editorconfig`).

I went through several resources:

- [How to find which isort is vscode exactly using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62604348/how-to-find-which-isort-is-vscode-exactly-using)
- [VSCode: how to config 'Organize imports' for Python (isort)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67059648/vscode-how-to-config-organize-imports-for-python-isort)
- [Sorting imports fails on Python VSCode extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69586036/sorting-imports-fails-on-python-vscode-extension)
- https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3306
- isort documentation

And this is my config that does not work:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python",
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.organizeImports": true
        }
    },
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "isort.check": true,
    "isort.logLevel": "debug",
    "isort.args": [
        "--settings",
        "/Users/myname/dev/myproject/.isort.cfg",
    ],
```

My `.isort.cfg`

```
[settings]
profile=hug
```

On save this is my `isort's` `OUTPUT` in VSCode:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3 -m isort - --settings /Users/myname/dev/myproject/.isort.cfg --filename /Users/myname/dev/myproject/api/src/models/album.py
CWD Linter: /Users/myname/dev/myproject
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3 -m isort - --settings /Users/myname/dev/myproject/.isort.cfg --check --filename /Users/myname/dev/myproject/api/src/models/album.py
CWD Linter: /Users/myname/dev/myproject
```

Comment: Note to self, this issue might have an answer: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-isort/issues/71